# Pass methods to use on a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, arguments

So I've come across a small problem here. I have simple jQuery function to see if the given element/elements are in the current viewport. See code below.

```
 function checkIfInViewport(element) {
  $(element).each(function() {
    let divPos = $(this).offset().top,
      topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (divPos < topOfWindow + 600) {
      $(this)
        .addClass('animated bounceInLeft')
        .css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
}
```

My question is how I can get rid of hard coding the addClass and css methods and instead call the function like:

```
checkIfInViewport(element, {methods I want to use});
```

So I don't have to specify what I want to do with the elements in the function itself, I want to pass to the function what I want it to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be easier to write `$(element).filter(isInViewport).addClass('animated bounceInLeft').css('opacity', 1);`

Comment: Btw, don't hardcode 600px. Check the screen size.

Comment: Is ”isInViewport” built in with jQuery or what is that?

Comment: No, that's the function you'd write yourself to take an element and return a boolean according to your rules. Should be much simpler than the callback approach in @Taplar's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the logic to a function, and pass it in as an argument to the function.  This is commonly referred to as a `callback`.

```js
function checkIfInViewport(element, callback) {
  $(element).each(function() {
    let divPos = $(this).offset().top,
      topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (divPos < topOfWindow + 600) {
      callback(this);
    }
  });
}

function animateElementAndSetOpacity ( element ) {
  $(element)
    .addClass('animated bounceInLeft')
    .css('opacity', 1);
}

checkIfInViewport( someElement, animateElementAndSetOpacity );
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure i understand your question but if you want to pass configurable jquery properties to your function you should be able to use something like this :

```
 function checkIfInViewport(element, jqueryMethods, jqueryAttribute) {
    $(element).each(function() {
      let divPos = $(this).offset().top,
        topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (divPos < topOfWindow + 600) {
            for(var index in jqueryMethods) {
                var method = jqueryMethods[index];
                var attribute = jqueryAttribute[index];
                $(element)[method](attribute);
            }
        }
    });
}
checkIfInViewport(element, ['addClass', 'css'], ['animated bouceInLeft', {'opacity': '1'}]);
```